# How Can a GitHub Repo Have 165 views, but Only 1 unique visitor?

Tags: github, git-clone

I opened my first github repository and it says
it has 165 views, 1 unique visitor & 7 clones.

if i only have 1 unique visitor, ie me..
how can it have 7 clones or 165 views?

does each of my pageloads count as a view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, considering a visitor views one page at least and possibly multiple pages, the number of views is always greater or equal the number of unique visitors. If you have one unique visitor and 165 views it means that person loaded / refreshed one or multiple pages 165 times.

I would assume it’s the same for the number of clones but note you can absolutely clone a repository without visiting its pages if you have its url